# Inserting a file directly in a dossier

Tags: latex-misc

I am writing a text in LaTeX on my Mac with several chapters and have created a dossier in which I put the files associated with the document (various chapters, ...) However, when I create a new file I do not know how to put it directly in the dossier. (I must look for it and then transfer it to the dossier.) Could someone tell me how to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "dossier" do you mean you create a folder to hold the documents? If so, what Editor/Front End are you using to create the document? Does it use a Standard Apple Save Dialog? If so, simply change the to the folder of your choice in that dialog; that folder will be remembered.

Comment: I should have said 'folder' not 'dossier'. I am using Texworks, which does not seem to have a command allowing one to save a new file in a given folder, or at least I have not found it. I hope this clarifies the pb.

Comment: The first time you Save the file you get a dialog box asking for a name for the file. That dialog box also allows you to pick a folder for your file.